# JS Function Change Value

Tags: javascript

so the first half of this works. The button ID "oneChange" changes the href link properly on click.. but it wont change the data-value for the element ID "data-target".

I'm using http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/

Thanks

```
 function f1()
{       
   var link = document.getElementById("ramchange");
   link.setAttribute("href", "xyz.php");
   var target = document.getElementById('data-target');
   gauge.set("1024");   
   return false;       
}
```

Update: Per comment suggestion, still doesn't work. Did I do this right?

```
{   
   var link = document.getElementById("ramchange");
   link.setAttribute("href", "cart.php?a=add&pid=1");
   target = document.querySelector('[data-target="target"]');
   console.log(target.value="1024");
   return false;

}
```

Comment: You're not setting the `data-value` for the `data-target` element. All you're doing is setting the gauge value. You get a reference to the `data-target` element called `target`, but you never use it.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not good with JS! so I assume I need to change "gauge.set("1024");" to something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can select your element `data-target` using `document.querySelector()` Like this..

```js
target = document.querySelector('[data-target="target"]');
target.setAttribute("data-target","new value");
console.log(target.getAttribute("data-target"));
console.log(target.textContent);
```

```html
<p data-target='target'>Some text</p>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks. So how does this Change the value? ex) data-value="0" ... click button.... data-value="1024"

Comment: just try using `target.value=1024;`

Comment: trying with changing `target = document.querySelector('[data-value="0"]');` then set `target.setAttribute('data-value","1024");`.

Comment: @FrozenSnow i have edited the answer with how can you set and get values.Follow the same way for your `data-value="0"`.

Comment: Okay. I am trying to change the "data-value" of element ID "data-target". In your answer which "data-target" do I switch to "value"?